# How can I change font of Table's caption while keeping its font type unchanged

Tags: fonts, captions

I am using `IEEEtran` template where caption of Tables's font size looks smaller than their published papers.

template code:

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for\\ IEEE Computer Society Journals}
\markboth{Journal of \LaTeX\ Class Files,~Vol.~14, No.~8, August~2015}%
\IEEEraisesectionheading{\section{Introduction}\label{sec:introduction}}
\IEEEPARstart{T}{his} demo file
\begin{table}[!t]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \caption{A Simple Example Table} \label{table_example}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c||c} \hline
      \bfseries First & \bfseries Next\\
      \hline\hline 1.0 & 2.0\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Here Table caption's font is different than the overall paper, where I was not able to increase its font while keeping the Table's unique font type unchanged.

---

As an example on IEEE's publish paper when I zoom in, the font is little bit larger for the Table's caption (I only able to capture its pdf view not sure would it help). When I put side-by-side right table (published paper's caption font look larger.)

[image]

I just want to slightly increase font-size of the Table's caption while keeping its original font-type unchanged.

Comment: If you are submitting a paper to the IEEE do not change the formatting; they may  use a different version of the class for their published printed documents.

Comment: @PeterWilson I have a very packed paper, I just wanted to see the spacing overall the paper beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight change to your MWE:

```
% captionprob.tex  SE 664313
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for\\ IEEE Computer Society Journals}
\markboth{Journal of \LaTeX\ Class Files,~Vol.~14, No.~8, August~2015}%
\IEEEraisesectionheading{\section{Introduction}\label{sec:introduction}}
\IEEEPARstart{T}{his} demo file
\begin{table}[!t]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
%    \caption{A Simple Example Table} \label{table_example}
    \caption{{\Huge A Simple Example Table}} \label{table_example} %%% change here
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c||c} \hline
      \bfseries First & \bfseries Next\\
      \hline\hline 1.0 & 2.0\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why did you use `\Huge`?

Comment: I just wanted to show one method of changing the look of the caption. It is entirely up to you how to do it in your document. Don't expect anyone to explicitly solve your problem but we at least try to indicate a potential route. You normally have to expect to do do some work yourself.

Comment: Instead of `\Huge`, using `\normalsize` helped.  But not sure is it the exact format `IEEE formatting` uses, hopefully it is.